# How do I end an Open Borders agreement in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5

I'd like my neighbor to stop moving units through my territory, but I can't seem to find an option to cancel our Open Borders agreement.  In the deal history screen, I can see an Open Borders agreement from well over 30 turns ago that doesn't even show up under Active Deals.  The trade screen just says that we already have an Open Borders agreement.  Am I missing something, or is there no way for me to cancel this agreement?

Comment: I am having the same problem. The open border aggreement was to last 30 turns and 100 turns later it is still in effect. No way to cancel except if you attack them but then you are hated by all civs because you broke an aggreement. Seems to me like it is a bug

Comment: Looks like this is what happened in my case, and it's a bug that will be fixed in the next patch ("Fix for never ending deals", see http://www.giantbomb.com/news/big-civ-5-patch-incoming-will-address-tons-of-issues/2635/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to cancel an Open Borders agreement. You just have to wait for whatever turns remain for it to expire.

Or you can go to war with them, which "kind of" cancels it :)

Comment: ... which is a problem if the reason you're trying to end the agreement is because their military units are stomping all over your territory :)

Answer (score 6):

Agreements can't simply be canceled, that's why they're *agreements for a certain number of turns*. Think *contracts*. You have to decide if you're able and willing to handle the terms of the agreement (contract) before committing to it. If you break the agreement, it has serious retributions (or rather, you have to go to extreme lengths, war, and face the backlash to break an agreement). If that wasn't so there would be little point to most agreements.

> "Yeah, let's do this *defensive pact* thing, unless of course you're being attacked, at which point I may simply decide to back out of the agreement..."

---

Update (2010/10/14): Apparently your problem *is* a bug and will be fixed.

http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=94438

> - Diplomacy – Fix for never ending deals (peace, research agreements, etc).

Comment: Having said that, what you're describing sounds like a bug. Unless you missed something...